# How to checkout a file from a sharepoint server programatically in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, windows-7

I am trying to implement the following example from Microsoft:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.checkoutfile%28v=office.12%29.aspx

But unfortunately, I cannot find the correct assembly to add to my project in order to access Web_Reference_Folder (this is unknown, and Resharper doesn't automatically offer an option to add it).

I have read that I need to install the Sharepoint Services 3 with SP2, but this setup package is for server operating systems only, it won't run on my Windows 7 x64.

So which tools do I need to install, or which assemblies to add in order to work with Web_Reference_Folder?

Answer (score 0):

When you have added the Web Reference, a Web Reference folder will be added to the solution explorer. The Web Reference folder will include the name of the web host. 
For more information please see the below link

http://forums.asp.net/t/1531191.aspx?help+interpretting+msdn+article+

Hope this will help you.